# Would someone care to correct or confirm my Spanish sample?

Tags: traducción, gramática, español-neutral

I have a small computer program that I need to make multi-lingual. To that end, I have used a few of the online translators. They have not worked very well for me in the past but it gives me a place to start. If it makes a difference, I know they do not sound the same at all, however, I am trying for Mexican-Spanish not Spanish-Spanish (From Spain).
Would someone care to correct or confirm my Spanish sample?

```
First Name
el nombre de pila

The First Name Property cannot be more than twenty-five characters in length.
La propiedad de nombre no puede ser más de 25 caracteres de longitud.

The First Name Property must be at least three characters in length.
La propiedad de nombre debe ser al menos tres caracteres de longitud.

The First Name Property is required and cannot be left blank.
La propiedad de nombre se requiere y no puede dejarse en blanco.
```

Kindest Reguards,

Randy

Comment: Hey Randy, welcome to Spanish.SE. I see that you took the [tour](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour). If you are new to Stack Exchange please visit the [help section](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) too. We discourage questions that are plain ["please correct my text"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since it would eventually turn this site into a "translation service", rather than a learning resource. I'm looking forward to seeing more contributions from you in the future!

Comment: Hello @Diego, a very long time ago I had three years of Spanish in high school. I took one year of Spanish in college. While my Spanish is horrible, I can speak it better than I can read or write it. In fact, my adopted son is Mexican and we are now learning Spanish together. My program that I wrote is for instruction/demo on how to code for a multi-lingual audience. I did not want someone to correct my grammar while reading my code. I apologize for using this site as a translation service. I will ask my Spanish speaking friends for translating help in the future.

Comment: Maybe I failed to convey the message properly. While "correct my text" sounds a little bit like "do my homework", there are plenty of questions about translations, best way of conveying something, etc. Even plenty of questions about how to express some computer science terms in Spanish. So, it is not that we just don't do translations. We don't do "plain translations" but we try to help people understanding why a specific term may work best in a translation. As I said, feel welcomed here and please stick around. I'm sure you (and your son) might find this site useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is almost there, but I would remove "developer words" such as `First Name property` and leave it as `Name`

> First Name

`Nombre`

Reason: In Spanish we don't have to differentiate between First Name and Last Name (Nombre, Apellido) and although `Nombre de Pila` is technically correct, to me it seems `Nombre` is sufficient.

> The First Name Property cannot be more than twenty-five characters in length.

`El nombre no puede ser más de 25 caracteres.`

Which translates to "The name can not be more than 25 characters"

> The First Name Property must be at least 3 characters in length.

`El nombre tiene que ser al menos 3 caracteres`

Which translates to "The name must be at least 3 characters"

> The First Name Property is required and cannot be left blank.

`El nombre es requerido y no puede dejarse en blanco`

Which translates to "The name is required and cannot be left blank"

Comment: Muchas gracias @gtgaxiola. Tu respuesta me ayuda mucho.

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment to gtgaxiola's answer but I don't have enough reputation points to add comments yet).

That said, I would go with:

`El nombre no debe contener más de 25 caracteres` and

`El nombre debe contener al menos 3 caracteres`

That sounds more formal to me, and that's how I usually see it in Spanish web pages. Also, I think it may be because of the USA influence over Mexico that a passive voice has been proposed for the last sentence, but in Spanish passive tenses should actually be avoided. Instead, I would say:

`El nombre es necesario y no puede dejarse en blanco`

Note that while this option is a little bit more "free", it sounds better -as it usually is the case when translating.